# Independence within groups - which test?

Tags: self-study, independence

I have a table of data with three columns:

```
Gender      Profession      Salary
F           Teacher         12
M           Teacher         14
F           Engineer        19
```

I know that there is a variance of salary between genders (mean and median are different). And I know that part of this variance comes from the fact that females are have lower paid (to do this I used chisq.test with gender and profession).

I want to understand if there is a difference in the salary within professions for males and females. That is, if there wasn't a difference in the professions chosen, would there be a difference in salary anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest strategy would be to use a linear regression, via ordinary least squares (OLS). Write the model as such:

$salary=\alpha+\beta_1 female + \beta_2 engineer+ \beta_{3} artist...$

where gender, teacher, engineer, etc., are 1/0 dummy variables, and you would have K-1 profession variables for K professions. You omit male (or female if you choose) and one profession (teacher in my example) because they act as a reference group. That is not required, but you would have to specify no $\alpha$ intercept otherwise. Since you have a sample, what your model estimates is:
$salary=\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta_1} female+ \hat{\beta_2} engineer+ \hat{\beta_{3}} artist...\epsilon$

where the $\hat{}$ indicates an estimate of the population parameter. $\epsilon$ is the error or residual term, accounting for the leftover variability in salary that is not associated with gender and profession (things like education, social status, age, appearance, etc.). The interpretation of $\alpha$ is the salary for the reference group, in this case male teachers. The interpretation of $\beta$ coefficients for each profession is the average difference in salary between Teachers and that profession, independent of the relationship between salary and gender. The interpretation of $\beta_1$ is what you are after in your question - it shows you the difference between men and women after controlling for the differences associated with differing professions. It accounts for imbalanced employment in different professions.

There are many assumptions behind hypothesis testing in OLS, that you should be familiar with and be prepared to test on your data. There is also a wide range of specification tests that you can do to look at how well your basic model accounts for the variance in salary, among other things. They can be found in any standard intro to statistics text, or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions)

Linear regression can be estimated in almost every software program these days - even in Excel. I won't get into the matrix algebra of it, but if you are interested again, you can find it in most references.

Comment: And I don't need to add an interaction term? Something like sex*profession?

Comment: I have done this summary(aov(salary ~ gender +  profession)). Which are the values that tell me the difference among the genders once the profession variable is eliminated?

Comment: The interaction is to test whether the relationship between gender and salary differs based on the specific profession , or vice versa, the relationship between salary and profession depends on gender. These are valid questions and you can certainly test them.

Comment: in your R code, look at the p-values for each of the variables. That tells you if they have a statistically significant relationship, depending on the criterion level you select, e.g. 0.05, 0.01. Alternatively you can run a linear regression model to get the actual coefficients, so you can see the "effect" of each: summary(lm(salary~gender+profession))